# Ожидание нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, concurrency

Как сделать, чтобы запущенный метод ждал нажатие кнопки?

```
yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status = 1;
            synchronized (sMonitor) {
                sMonitor.notify();
            }
        }
    });


    noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status = 2;
            synchronized (sMonitor) {
                sMonitor.notify();
            }
        }
    });
...

private void askQuestion1() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Start");
            jokeTextView.setText(R.string.joke_1_1);
            synchronized (sMonitor) {
                try {
                    sMonitor.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (status == 1) {
                askQuestion2();
            }
            if (status == 2) {
                askQuestion6();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

....

```
private void askQuestion2() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jokeTextView.setText(R.string.joke_1_2);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Что-нибудь в стиле `while (!isClicked) { Thread.sleep(1000); }` с установкой значения `isClicked` в `true` в методе обработки нажатия клавиш?

Comment: Покажите имеющийся код.

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв правильно ли я понимаю, что если вопросов будет 100, то вы создадите 100 методов `askQuestionXX`?

Comment: там не будет 100 вопросов, метод нужен для возвращения на предыдущие методы исходя из выбранного ответа

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя делать `Thread.sleep(...)` в UI-потоке, ибо если Вы заблокируете UI-поток, то, спустя несколько секунд, получите ANR (*Application not responding*) с предложением о принудительной остановке приложения. Да и вообще нельзя загружать UI-поток.

В Вашей задаче необходимо создать новый поток, в котором будет выполнятся Ваш метод и использовать синхронизацию потоков (например) на каком-либо объекте.

Вот самый примитивный код, который выполняет поставленную задачу:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mFirstButton;
    private Button mSecondButton;

    private static final Object sMonitor = new Object();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button);
        mSecondButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_button);

        mFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Start");
                        synchronized (sMonitor) {
                            try {
                                sMonitor.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", "End");
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        mSecondButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                synchronized (sMonitor) {
                    sMonitor.notify();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

При нажатии кнопки `mFirstButton` запускается новый поток, в лог выводится соответствующее сообщение, далее поток входит в синхронизированный блок, выполняется метод `wait()` и поток засыпает.

Далее, при нажатии `mSecondButton`, UI-поток входит в синхронизированный блок (а войти он может потому, что запущенный по кнопке `mFirstButton` поток после вызова `wait()` уже не владеет монитором) и вызывает `notify()`, что влечет за собой возобновление работы потока, созданного по кнопке `mFirstButton`.

**UPD**:

Для того чтобы выполнить код в главном потоке, можно воспользоваться, например, методом `runOnUiThread(...)`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // actions on UI-thread
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: а как можно вернуться на основной поток, для изменения активности?

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, Добавил в ответ.

Comment: я пробовал это но ide не пропускает, обновил код в вопросе

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, В коде, который находится в вопросе, не вызова метода `runOnUiThread(...)`.

Comment: обновил код, runOnUiThread показывает красным и предлагает создать метод

Comment: нашел решение getActivity().runOnUiThread так работает

Answer (score -1):

```
boolean mark = false;
OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {  
        mark = true;
    }
};
while(!mark) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, получаю белый экран, убираю цикл while все работает, вот мой метод `private void askQuestion1() {
        jokeTextView.setText(R.string.joke_1_1);
        while (!isClicked) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (status == 1) {
            askQuestion2();
        }
        if (status == 2) {
            askQuestion6();
        }

    }`

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв, `Thread.sleep(...);` нельзя делать в UI-потоке.